# UINavigationItem position in Navigation Bar is not changing on Orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have added custom image on right navigation item in a Navigation bar. But when i rotate the device the right button item stick to the portrait position.

Portrait

[image]

Landscape

[image]

As you can see that the menu icon stick to its original position when changing from Portrait to Landscape.

Code

```
    let menuImage = UIImage(named: "right_menu_icon.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)


    var right_menu_button = CBarButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as CBarButton
    right_menu_button.setBackgroundImage(menuImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    right_menu_button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"right_menu_icon_highlight.png"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    right_menu_button.addTarget(self, action: "menuButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    right_menu_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, menuImage!.size.width, menuImage!.size.height)
    right_menu_button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin


    var rightButton:UIBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(customView: right_menu_button)
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Comment: This fixes my issue. right_menu_button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

Answer (score 0):

try removing this code:

```
right_menu_button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleleftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
```

or change it to:

```
right_menu_button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
```

Comment: No. This will make a button stretched.